# Getting Geolocation data from address data using a Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, geolocation

I am trying to get Latitude and Longitude from  Location in a Google sheet

Location column = N

Latitude column = O

Longitude column = P

The function throws an error, this part

`var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);`

if the value of a cell in the location column is not in the form that can be given coordinates ex; empty cell or "Chile"

What I need when this happens is to give `lat & lng` an empty value i.e

lat=lng=""

I am trying to use

```
    try{}
    catch(e){}
```

The error handling function runs but nothing is output

Thanks

The original function

```
 function geoCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var cells = range.getValues();
   
  var latitudes = [];
  var longitudes = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
   var address = cells[i][13];
   var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
   var res = geocoder.results[0];
 
   var lat = lng = 0;
   if (res) {
     lat = res.geometry.location.lat;
     lng = res.geometry.location.lng;
   }
   
  latitudes.push([lat]);
  longitudes.push([lng]);
}
   
  sheet.getRange('O2')
  .offset(0, 0, latitudes.length).setValues(latitudes);
  sheet.getRange('P2').offset(0, 0, longitudes.length).setValues(longitudes);
}
```

With error handling

```
 function geoCode2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var cells = range.getValues();
   
  var latitudes = [];
  var longitudes = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var address = cells[i][13];
    
  try {
   var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
   var res = geocoder.results[0];
 
   var lat = lng = 0;
   if (res) {
     lat = res.geometry.location.lat;
     lng = res.geometry.location.lng;
  }
   
  latitudes.push([lat]);
  longitudes.push([lng]);
  }
 
 catch(e) {
  var lat = lng = "";
  latitudes.push([lat]);
  longitudes.push([lng]);
  continue;//If error continue looping
}
}
  sheet.getRange('O2')
  .offset(0, 0, latitudes.length).setValues(latitudes);
  sheet.getRange('P2').offset(0, 0, longitudes.length).setValues(longitudes);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing is output*? What do you expect to be output and what actually has turnedm happened?

Comment: The error function runs but no Lat or Lng coordinates are output.  I expect latitude and longitude coordinates to be output for properly formated locations

Comment: Have you tried running `var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address)` in isolation and then logging the result? What do you get? Does it give an error even with properly formatted locations? You mention an error, can you post the error message?

Comment: It does run on properly formatted data

Comment: error is `Exception: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I guess it only errors on an empty cell value

```
 function geoCode() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var cells = range.getValues();
   
  var latitudes = [];
  var longitudes = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < cells.length; i++) {
   var address = cells[i][1];
   
    if(address =="") {
      lat = ""
      lng = ""
      latitudes.push([lat]);
      longitudes.push([lng]);
    } else{
    
      var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);
      var res = geocoder.results[0];
 
      var lat = lng = 0;
      if (res) {
       lat = res.geometry.location.lat;
       lng = res.geometry.location.lng;
     }
   
     latitudes.push([lat]);
     longitudes.push([lng]);
  }
 }
   
  sheet.getRange('C2')
  .offset(0, 0, latitudes.length).setValues(latitudes);
  sheet.getRange('D2').offset(0, 0, longitudes.length).setValues(longitudes);
}
```